# Javascript display(); no showing pop, push, unshift, shift?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I am learning pop, push, shift, and unshift. I am trying to have 3 movies, display all 4 of them at different time. However, my .display(); function isn't showing anything. I am getting an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: ArrayOfMovies.push is not a function
```

I believe it is going to be the same issue with the other .display(); element.

```
function Movie(title, genre, rating, price, img) {
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.price = price;
    this.image = img;
    this.display = displaymovie;
}

function displaymovie() {
document.write("<blockquote style='text-align:left; font-size:15px; font-family: Arial, sans-sherif; font-weight:600; float:left; padding-left: 20px; padding-right:40px; padding-top:40px; color:#C58917;'>Title:" + this.title + "<br>");
document.write("Genre:" + this.genre + "<br>");
document.write("Rating:" + this.rating + "<br>");
document.write("Price:" + this.price + "</blockquote><br>");
document.write("<span><IMG float:'right' SRC='" + this.image + "' style='width:138px; height:158px;'>" + "<BR><BR>");
}

var movieone = new Movie(" Avengers the age of Ultron", " Action / Adventure", " 8.0/10.0", " $9.99", "Labs_Images/Avg_Ultron.jpg");
var movietwo = new Movie(" The Age of Adaline", " Drama / Romance", " 6.7/10.0", " $8.99, ", "Labs_Images/Tmrr_land.jpg");
var moviethree = new Movie(" The Age of Adaline", " Drama / Romance", " 6.7/10.0", " $8.99", "Labs_Images/MM_road.jpg");

var ArrayOfMovies = new Movie ();
ArrayOfMovies.push(movieone);
ArrayOfMovies.push(movietwo);
ArrayOfMovies.push(moviethree);
var MoviesAll = Movie.push();
     MoviesAll.display();

        document.write("<br> <br>", "<h2>Next</h2>", "<br> <br>");

        var MovieAll = ArrayOfMovies.pop();
         MovieAll.display();
        document.write("<br> <br>", "<h2>Next2</h2>", "<br> <br>");

        var MovieAll2 = ArrayOfMovies.pop();
         MovieAll2.display();
        document.write("<br> <br>", "<h2>Next3</h2>", "<br> <br>");

        var MovieAll3 = ArrayOfMovies.unshift('movietwo');
        var MovieAll4 = ArrayOfMovies.pop();
         MovieAll4.display();
        document.write("<br> <br>", "<h2>Next4</h2>", "<br> <br>");

        var MovieAll5 = ArrayOfMovies.push('moviethree');
        var MovieAll6 = ArrayOfMovies.shift();
         MovieAll6.display();
```

Comment: `var ArrayOfMovies = new Movie ();` ==> `var ArrayOfMovies = [];`

Comment: I changed it var ArrayOfMovies = []; still not working.

Comment: `var MoviesAll = Movie.push()` - `Movie` I assume is an object constructor function, meaning it does not have a `.push()` method on it. What is `MoviesAll` supposed to equal exactly?

Comment: Since you changed ArrayOfMovies to an array (as stated in your comment), you should be getting a different error since (Uncaught TypeError: ArrayOfMovies.push is not a function) is not true anymore. What is the new error?

Comment: @sam I'm still receiving the same error. I tried first ArrayOfMovies.display(); because i want to see the new array with push of movieone, movietwo,moviethree. It didnt work, so i create a other var MoviesAll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this is what you were looking for right:

```js
function Movie(title, genre, rating, price, img) {
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.price = price;
    this.image = img;
}

// Just a better way to add methods to the objects prototype
Movie.prototype.display = function() {
    document.write("<blockquote style='text-align:left; font-size:15px; font-family: Arial, sans-sherif; font-weight:600; float:left; padding-left: 20px; padding-right:40px; padding-top:40px; color:#C58917;'>Title:" + this.title + "<br>");
    document.write("Genre:" + this.genre + "<br>");
    document.write("Rating:" + this.rating + "<br>");
    document.write("Price:" + this.price + "</blockquote><br>");
    document.write("<span><IMG float:'right' SRC='" + this.image + "' style='width:138px; height:158px;'>" + "<BR><BR>");
};

var movieone = new Movie(" Avengers the age of Ultron", " Action / Adventure", " 8.0/10.0", " $9.99", "Labs_Images/Avg_Ultron.jpg");
var movietwo = new Movie(" The Age of Adaline", " Drama / Romance", " 6.7/10.0", " $8.99, ", "Labs_Images/Tmrr_land.jpg");
var moviethree = new Movie(" The Age of Adaline", " Drama / Romance", " 6.7/10.0", " $8.99", "Labs_Images/MM_road.jpg");

// Creates an array for the movies
var ArrayOfMovies = [];

// Pushes some movies
ArrayOfMovies.push(movieone);
ArrayOfMovies.push(movietwo);
ArrayOfMovies.push(moviethree);

document.write("<br> <br>", "<h2>Next</h2>", "<br> <br>");

// Proper pop()
var movie = ArrayOfMovies.pop();
movie.display();
document.write("<br> <br>", "<h2>Next2</h2>", "<br> <br>");

// Proper shift()
movie = ArrayOfMovies.shift();
movie.display();
document.write("<br> <br>", "<h2>Next3</h2>", "<br> <br>");

// Proper push() and pop()
ArrayOfMovies.push(movietwo);
movie = ArrayOfMovies.pop();
movie.display();
document.write("<br> <br>", "<h2>Next4</h2>", "<br> <br>");

// Proper unshift() and shift()
ArrayOfMovies.unshift(moviethree);
movie = ArrayOfMovies.shift();
movie.display();
```

Comment: I see you took out  the object this.display = displaymovie; from the function Movie(title, genre, rating, price, img). and you created Movie.prototype.display = function() why? thanks!

Comment: FYI : correction both movie.display(); were missing the semicolon to close it. As well as Movie.prototype.display = function() {
};    thanks! Now it runs perfectly!

Comment: The reason I did that was because there was no need to have that as a global function. Plus, it's much better to put methods (functions on an object) on the prototype instead of inside the constructor function.

Comment: Thanks on the semicolon thing. That's fixed now.

Comment: What did you change/fix?

Comment: Why would either one of those missing semicolons have made a difference?

Comment: @sam hum ok I see. But the .push (movieone), (movietwo), and (moviethree) arent displaying? is normal? I' am trying to dispay them via var movie2 = ArrayOfMovies.push(movieone);
movie2.display(); individually... no much success so far...

Comment: @torazaburo They wouldn't. But I'd prefer to maintain a habit of always ending statements with a semicolon instead of falling prey to auto semicolon insertion errors.

Comment: @Sow `.push` returns a number which is the length of the array after the item is pushed onto it. So the value of `movie2` is a number equal to however long the array is after you do `var movie2 = ArrayOfMovies.push(movieone);`. It's not equal to the object that's being pushed. After pushing, you'd have to do something like `var movie2 = ArrayOfMovies[ArrayOfMoves.length - 1]` to grab the last item in the array.

Comment: Yes, one should always use semicolons. But I'm confused: if the semicolons here did not actually matter, and if that is all you changed, then why does your code work when the OP's did not?

Comment: @torazaburo, I'm actually not sure. It worked for me with and without the semicolons, but I was using Chrome's console.

Answer (score 0):

@torazaburo you have to have semicolon because is part of the JavaScript programming language. If you dont JavaScript will automatically Insert a semicolon. Check this blog out: 
-[JavaScript Semicolon Insertion: Every you need to know](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons). 
It tells you more about the rules. In some case the semicolon can be omitted as well.

Answer (score 0):

After I read Sam comment I figure out the easier way which it need:

```
var movie = ArrayOfMovies[ArrayOfMovies.length - 3];
movie.display();
var movie = ArrayOfMovies[ArrayOfMovies.length - 2];
movie.display();
var movie = ArrayOfMovies[ArrayOfMovies.length - 1];
movie.display(); //now the pushed are all dispayled!
```

Here is the full Javascript after my corrections --- >

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Movie(title, genre, rating, price, img) {
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.price = price;
    this.image = img;
}

// Just a better way to add methods to the objects prototype
Movie.prototype.display = function() {
    document.write("<blockquote style='text-align:left; font-size:15px; font-family: Arial, sans-sherif; font-weight:600; float:left; padding-left: 20px; padding-right:40px; padding-top:40px; color:#C58917;'>Title:" + this.title + "<br>");
    document.write("Genre:" + this.genre + "<br>");
    document.write("Rating:" + this.rating + "<br>");
    document.write("Price:" + this.price + "</blockquote><br>");
    document.write("<span><IMG float:'right' SRC='" + this.image + "' style='width:138px; height:158px;'>" + "<BR><BR>");
};

var movieone = new Movie(" Avengers the age of Ultron", " Action / Adventure", " 8.0/10.0", " $9.99", "Labs_Images/Avg_Ultron.jpg");
var movietwo = new Movie(" The Age of Adaline", " Drama / Romance", " 6.7/10.0", " $8.99, ", "Labs_Images/Tmrr_land.jpg");
var moviethree = new Movie(" The Age of Adaline", " Drama / Romance", " 6.7/10.0", " $8.99", "Labs_Images/MM_road.jpg");




document.write("<br> <br>", "<h2>Next</h2>", "<br> <br>");
// Creates an array for the movies
var ArrayOfMovies = [];

// Pushes some movies
ArrayOfMovies.push(movieone);
ArrayOfMovies.push(movietwo);
ArrayOfMovies.push(moviethree);

// Pushes some movies display
var movie = ArrayOfMovies[ArrayOfMovies.length - 3];
movie.display();
var movie = ArrayOfMovies[ArrayOfMovies.length - 2];
movie.display();
var movie = ArrayOfMovies[ArrayOfMovies.length - 1];
movie.display();
document.write("<br> <br>", "<h2>Next2</h2>", "<br> <br>");

// Proper pop()
var movie = ArrayOfMovies.pop();
movie.display();
document.write("<br> <br>", "<h2>Next3</h2>", "<br> <br>");

// Proper shift()
movie = ArrayOfMovies.shift();
movie.display();
document.write("<br> <br>", "<h2>Next4</h2>", "<br> <br>");

// Proper push() and pop()
ArrayOfMovies.push(movietwo);
movie = ArrayOfMovies.pop();
movie.display();
document.write("<br> <br>", "<h2>Next5</h2>", "<br> <br>");

// Proper unshift() and shift()
ArrayOfMovies.unshift(moviethree);
movie = ArrayOfMovies.shift();
movie.display();
</script>
```

Comment: @sam Thank you very much!

Comment: @torazaburo well the rules are kind of trick but when I published into the server to look and open it on Google chrome. I saw the notification in the command console of the missing semicolons. After, I don't how it worked for you with out issues.